# golang panic: nil map

Tags: golang, map, struct

при работе получается ввести 1 значение для Twice, а дальше пишет:
panic: assignment to entry in nil map
Буду признателен, если кто объяснит из-за чего это.

//изучаю ЯП и вообще я новичок в этих делах.

```
   package main
   
type Once struct {
    name  string
    somthingInt   int
    
}
type newText string

type Twice struct {
    tempMap map[newText]*Once
}
func (v Twice) Put(stud Once) (tmpU Twice, err error) {
    found := true
    NameForKeyStruct := newText(thisOnce.name)

    _, found = v.tempMap[NameForKeyStruct]
    if !found {
        v.tempMap[NameForKeyStruct] = &thisOnce
    } else {
        return tmpU, err
    }
return tmpU, nil
}

func main() {
    var tmpU Twice
    TmpU.tempMap = map[studentName]*thisOnce
    var thisOnce Once
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("enter Once details")
    for {
        tmp := scanner.Text()
        slice := strings.SplitN(tmp, " ", -1)
        if len(slice) == 3 {
            var err error
            thisOnce.name = (slice[0])
            thisOnce.somthingInt, err = strconv.Atoi(slice[1])
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("data base append")
            fmt.Println("wait to input...")
            TmpU, err = (&TmpU).Put(*&thisIsOnce)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%#v\nNot try old name!", err)
                }
            slice = nil
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Not full information")
            fmt.Println("wait to input...")
        }
        if scanner.Scan() == false {
            break
        }
    }
fmt.Printf("значения Twice:%v", tmpU)
}
```

// Удалил вопрос о "return _, err"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

требовалось в func main() добавить `make`  в строку "`TmpU.tempMap = map[studentName]*thisOnce`"

пример: `TmpU.tempMap = make(map[studentName]*thisOnce)`
и после начало принимать больше 1 значения для этой map и больше не вызывать panic

спасибо за подсказку насчёт `return nil`

Answer (score 0):

строки вида `var1, var2 := myFunction()` работают следующим образом, что первый результат функции присваивается на `var1`, второй на `var2`.
в языке есть строгие ограничения, что все переменные должны быть использованы.
Тогда прибегаем к стилю

```
_, var2 := myFunction()
var1, _ := myFunction()
_, _:= myFunction()
```

что означает

1. я заинтересован только в значении var2, а про var1 можно забыть
2. я заинтересован только в значении var1, а про var2 можно забыть
3. мне не нужны результаты функции. указывается, чтобы явно об этом говорить читающему код

так как `_` не обладает никаким значением и не является переменным, то вы не сможете его возвращать как результат функции `return _, err`

если функция требует возвращение какого либо значения, то в случае ошибки верните nil или значение по умолчанию

```
func f1() (string, error) {
    return "", fmt.Errorf("error")
}

func f2() (*string, error) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("error")
}
```